# File IO relative to JAR/WAR program

Tags: java, jar, clojure, io, relative-path

My app does some file IO. My project.clj has the following:

```clj
:resource-paths ["resources" "target/cljsbuild" "../output"]
```

And one of the IO operations includes something like this:

```clj
(defn serve-pdf
  "Check whether pdf-id.pdf exists already;
  If not, create. Then, return it. "
  [submission-id & [force]]
  (let [pdf-name (str submission-id ".pdf")
        out-dir (-> "leave" io/resource io/file) ;; TODO create this if not exists
        pdf-file (-> (str (.getPath out-dir) (java.io.File/separator) pdf-name)
                     io/file)]
    (if (or (not (.exists pdf-file))
            force)
      (all-out-pdf submission-id (.getPath pdf-file)))
    pdf-file))
```

The problem is, while this works nicely from REPL, it wont' work from War (since ../ is something different). How can I have it working in a directory structure that contains the "leave" folder as a sibling to myapp.war?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: JARs and WARs don't know about any file systems.  It's easy to do input using getResourceAsStream() from context path, but you've got a problem with output to file systems and directories.

Comment: Oops. Question included now :)

Comment: Don't call `io/file` on a resource ever since this is exactly the problem you get. They stop being files in WARs. You have to create your files outside of the resource directory. Alternative would be to extract your war for deployment

Comment: the resource io/file problem is understood and fixed, but this question really does concern itself with files (not resources): the need to read/write PDF files somewhere relative to the JAR file.